# Remove duplicates entries between two tables

Tags: php, mysql

I have to tables that contains to categories cat 1 and cat 2

```
| cat| name   |
===============
| 1  | PHP    |
| 1  | Jee    |
| 1  | VB.NET |
| 2  | PHP    |
| 2  | Jee    |
| 2  | VB.NET |
| 1  | C#     |
```

As you can see PHP, Jee, and VB.NET are common records between the cat 1 and cat 2.

I want to select only the names from cat 1 that have no duplicates on cat 2  -- > C#

I have tried something like this :

```
$query="SELECT name FROM `table1` WHERE `cat` = 1 
        NOT IN ( SELECT name FROM `table1` WHERE `cat` = 2  )";
```

But its giving No result blank page

UPDATE : i have figure out the answer myself :

```
$query="SELECT name FROM `table1` WHERE `cat` = 1";
$result = mysql_query($query);
while( $row = mysql_fetch_array($result ))

{

$query2="SELECT name FROM `table1` WHERE `cat` = 2 and name =".$row['name'];
$result2 = mysql_query($query2);
$row2 = mysql_fetch_array($result2)

if($row2['name']==""){

echo $row['name'];

}

}
```

Comment: Did you read even the most basic SQL tutorial or spec?

Comment: @developerwjk Can I have a guess at that one?

Comment: why would various names have the same category id anyway?  This lacks context really bad.

Comment: Thnx Found the answer chek the Update

Answer (score 0):

You don't get any results from your query, because the query syntax is incorrect. Checking for errors (or executing the query in another tool, outside of your script) should have informed you about that.

```
SELECT name
FROM `table1`
WHERE `cat` = 1 
AND name NOT IN (
    SELECT name FROM `table1` WHERE `cat` = 2
)
```

Note the added `AND name` in front of `NOT IN`.